# Why do I see an ad for a past event?

Tags: support, advertising

I missed the WAD Congress in my home town for the second time in a row:

[image]

Does Stack Overflow want to punish me for AWOL by showing the ad for the event that took place from May 16th to 18th, more than two weeks ago?

Comment: sounds familiar ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253156/158100

Comment: yes. Stack Overflow work with the FBI in tracking who goes to what events. We know you've been a naughty boy not going to see Joel. We'll be at your door at 23 00

Comment: Poor use of an advertising budget.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

The ads for the WAD Congress have been paused, so you shouldn't see any more nasty reminders... until maybe next year.

Comment: you may wish to update the year when you get there ;-)